# Visual Studio and NUnit -> missing test menu items

Tags: nunit

If you look at the video at exactly:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BDiFbQ5GN8#t=5m50s

... you will see that right click on dll project in solution explorer, the menu shows "Run Tests(s)" and "Test With". Then NUnit pops up outside of VS and runs the tests.

I have NUnit installed and if I open the dll file I am trying to test I can run it outside of Visual Studio. But I do not get the associated project testing menu items.

How do I integrate it as it is in the youtube video tutorial? I have tried on VS2010 and VS2013, and I have tried various related NuGet packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a feature of [TestDriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/).  It's mentioned in the [quick start guide here](http://www.testdriven.net/quickstart.aspx).